# WGCNA module preservation

Tags: r, wgcna

I am completing the online tutorials for module preservation of human brain modules in chimpanzee brains and vice versa (III). If anyone is aware of this tutorial or practiced before wondering if can help with quick question please.
I completed sections 1a and 2a to upload the expression data and then proceeded to Appendix A to complete Network Analysis of expression data. Within the code; I get error: Object ConnectivityHuman or Error: Object ConnectivityChimp not found. I have searched for any Sections of tutorial missed but unable to find these? Anyone any advice on tutorial gratefully appreciated thank you

```
ConnectivityHuman = ConnectivityHuman/max(ConnectivityHuman)
    ConnectivityChimp = ConnectivityChimp/max(ConnectivityChimp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. Looks like we forgot to include two important lines. Something along the lines of

```
ConnectivityHuman = colSums(adjHuman)-1
ConnectivityChimp = colSums(adjChimp)-1
```

This should do it; I'll update the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You are always so so helpful. Thank you this will make me sleep better tonight! Kind regards